# How to enable grey rectangular backgrounds on mouseover similar to Office 365?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HEue6/1/ that looks good for a start and now I want it to look and feel more like Office 365. I think the font in Office 365 is Segoe UI Semilight but I'm not sure. In the meantime we've used the Google font Raleway but another font that was mentioned is also called Futura. Now I would like to add the effect that also Office 365 has, that a grey rectangular box marks the selected area.

[image]

Can you help me? Do you think that the correct font is chosen or can it get more similar to Office 365? How should I add the grey rectangle for a chosen element?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>-Register</title>

    <script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/scripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,200" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="header">
    <div id="header-title">Account Administration</div>
</div>
<hr />

<div id="navigation-bar">
    <div id="navigation-content">

        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->  <a href="/admin/adduser">
        <div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Add new account</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Add new user account</div>
        </div></a>

        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->
        <a href="/admin/search"><div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Search account</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Search and manage accounts</div>
        </div></a>


        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->
        <a href="/admin/export"><div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Export</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Export to Excel and other formats</div>
        </div></a>

        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->

        <form id="inputForm" role="form" class="marg-left" action="/admin/import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="upload" name="file" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();"/><a href="" id="upload_link"><div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Import</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Import from tab-separated files on disk</div>
        </div>   </a>

        </form>

        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->
<a href="/admin/setup"> <div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Setup</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Setup global parameters</div>
        </div></a>

        <!-- SINGLE BUTTON MODULE -->
<a href="j_spring_security_logout"><div class="navigation-button" id="logga">
            <div class="navigation-header">Logout</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Exit account administration</div>
        </div></a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use Firebug or Chrome dev tools to inspect individual elements on Office 365 for general ideas on how they format elements?  As for the grey box, it appears to be simple CSS hover styles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a very quick and dirty implementation, but change your CSS to:

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEue6/2/)

```
body {
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #0072c9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 30;
}
#header-title {
    left: 250px;
    font-size: 22px;
    bottom: 7px;
    color: #0072c9;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
}
#navigation-bar {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
}
#navigation-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
}
.navigation-button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
.navigation-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #0072c9;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.navigation-desc {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0072c9;
}
#logout {
    border-top: solid 2px #0072c9;
}
#navigation-content a:hover div.navigation-button {
    background:lightgrey;
}
#navigation-content a:hover div.navigation-button:before {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:-20px;
    top:15px;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:white;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 5px 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```